# how to get last child of jstree inserted

Tags: javascript, jstree

I'm using `JsTree` for displaying new registered users, but I need to display the last user inserted node in the tree automatically, after the tree finished to load. For example making it selected as the tree loaded completely.

I tried to use `.bind("loaded.jstree")` but it doesn't work for me.